# macOS - menulet constant reload/flicker

Tags: macos, high-sierra, menu-bar

- macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

issue

- menulet keeps flicker and won't stop (randomly) sometimes it stop for a little while. I've done the standard disk utility, reboot, single user mode. Only thing remaining is to do a OS recovery reinstall.
- it only happens after the 5th menulet item. I can move the macOS menulet icon over and it'll do that with that with the macOS menulet icon too.

Video

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some menulet is trying to load but then failing. I would remove all the third-party menulets, and see if the behaviour persists. Look at the contents of `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist`, which contains the list of what menulets to load, and see what's there.

At worst, you could delete this file and reboot.

Also, see if the problem shows in a brand new user account - this will rule in or out whether it's a system-wide issue or specific to a user account. (and therefore whether re-installing is worthwhile.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did end up reinstall the OS and that didn't resolve the issue.  a new account didn't show that issue.  However, after the re-install it seemed to not have the issue then it returned and then it's as bad as before.  I have also removed the preference file to see if that resolves the issue.